# Regarding the behavior of string padding using str.ljust in python

Tags: python

I have a use case in which I am setting the labels for

```
matplotlib.colorbar
```

and I want to distribute the description evenly using the code below

```
temp = ""
for section in range(total_section_len):
    temp.ljust(60//(total_section_len * 5))
    temp += "stream 0"
    temp.ljust(60//(total_section_len * 5))
    temp += "stream 1"
    temp.ljust(60//(total_section_len * 5))
print temp
```

I am expecting something like

```
"    stream0     stream1     "
```

but instead what I get is

```
"stream0stream1"
```

Why does

```
str.ljust
```

behavior in such fashion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `ljust` is the "minimum" length of the string. It will only pad with spaces if this value is longer than the current length of the string.

Unless `total_section_len` is only 1, `60//(total_section_len * 5)` will be less than the length of your strings, so no padding is taking place.

Also, it doesn't modify the string in place as strings are immutable. You need to use the return value, `i.e. temp = temp.ljust(...)`

Answer (score 0):

ljust(width, fillchr) returns a left justified string by width specified and fills it with fillchr, whose default is empty space.

So

```
a = ''
b = a.ljust(10)
print(a)
>>> ''
print(b)
>>> '         '
```

It returns a left justified string to variable **b** and variable **a** is not modified.

and So this piece of code should work:

```
a = ''
a += ''.ljust(10) + 'stream0'
a += ''.ljust(10) + 'stream1'
print(a)
>>> '          stream0          stream1'
```